# Determining if a number is divisible by 1000

Tags: functions, number-theory

I have a number such as:

```
a = 875952;
```

And I want to find if it is divisible by 1000.

Is there a concise way of doing that?

Answer (score 17):

Use [`Divisible`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisible%60.html):

```
Divisible[a, 1000]
```

> False

Answer (score 9):

It depends whether you want a three-digit number, in which case try using `Mod`, as in:

```
Mod[a, 1000]
```

If you want a `List` of the digits, then the other solutions above work fine.

If your goal is instead to see whether `a` is (evenly) divisible by `1000`, then:

```
Mod[a,1000] == 0
```

yields a `True` or `False`.

Although I don't think this is quite what the OP requests, in response to @TheGreatDuck, here is (inefficient) code that gets the final three digits from any real number:

```
a = 3454.983745; 
Take[
 NestWhile[
 If[Last[#] == 0, Drop[#, -1]] &, RealDigits[a][[1]], 
  Last[#] == 0 &], -3]
```

Comment: Actually I want to see whether a is divisable by 1000, my ways is to judge the last number of a. But it seems complex. Do you have other ways? thanks.

Comment: A recommendation:  Always ask your *actual* question, rather than an intermediate question.  You're more likely to get better answers.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork but what if by last 3 digits we mean last 3 digits of even decimal fractions such as 13.535 returning 535 or the list {5,3,5} or any other equivalent representation? Right now your formula gives the last three whole number place values along with the decimal fraction. (And yes, I can see the askers usage/intention was something very different but it would be interesting to see a more precise answer to the original question.)

Comment: @TheGreatDuck:  The OP is rather confused about what is desired:  "Actually I want to see whether $a$ is divisable by 1000."  I tried to answer his actual question.  If the OP wants something different, I'm happy to address that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork no the op asked a completely different question in the comments. The desired question is what is posted in the question at the top of this page which asks for how "to get last 3 numbers of a". Your first formula does not do that. Any fraction will not return 3 numbers with that formula.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck look up what an x y question is. In this case the best approach would be to edit the original question as it is not the question that the OP wants to be answered.

Comment: @Fogmeister no they should ask a new question.